# How to sync a folder on Google drive to android

Tags: google-drive

My workflow is as follows:

1. Photos/videos from my camera's SD card are processed on a PC.
2. Final photos/videos are auto synced between a folder on the PC and Google Drive using Backup and Sync.
3. Photos/videos are downloaded from google drive android app to phone.
4. Photos/videos are used from phone on apps.

I have to do step 3 manually. Is there a way for my phone to download photos/videos from Google drive in the background so that they are available in the Gallery app when I need them.

Phone used: Samsung Note 10

Comment: Run `rclone sync` as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I use [Folder Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) for a very similar workflow. It works fine and I have it running on two devices. Additionally, you can setup up [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) for scheduled sync.

> FolderSync enables simple sync to cloud based storage to and from local folders

[Autosync for Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.drivesync) is another alternative

Comment: I don't use Google Drive. I use Pcloud